# Cannot get Row Headers to change color in Power BI with custom theme

Tags: powerbi, themes, customization

I have been creating a custom theme for my company in JSON for our Power BI reports, and I want to change both the column and row headers colors for the pivot table/matrix. I have been able to get the column headers to change color fine, but the row headers won't change. My code is below. The pivot table section is last.

```
{
    "name": "Custom Theme",
    "visualStyles":{
        "*":{
            "*":{
                "*":[{
                    "fontFamily":"Segoe UI",
                    "color":{"solid":{}}
                    }]
                }
            },
        "tableEx":{
            "*":{
                "columnHeaders":[{
                    "fontColor":{"solid":{"color":"#FFFFFF"}},
                    "backColor":{"solid":{"color":"#000000"}}
                }]
            }
        },
        "pivotTable":{
            "*":{
                "rowHeaders":[{
                    "fontColor":{"solid":{"color":"#FFFFFF"}},
                    "backColor":{"solid":{"color":"#000000"}}
                }],
                "columnHeaders":[{
                    "fontColor":{"solid":{"color":"#FFFFFF"}},
                    "backColor":{"solid":{"color":"#000000"}}
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already set the color manually it won't change due to a theme change. Also, you should consider that some values settings can affect row settings too.